# DataBind to ObservableCollection, displaying only elements of a certain derived class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, observablecollection

I am developing an application in WPF using the MVVM pattern and have come across something that may be a bit unique.

I have an abstract class `MapEntity` which represents an entity that can be displayed on a drawing surface of my application. Other classes such as `LineEntity`, `TextEntity`, etc, etc, inherit from `MapEntity`.

To display these, I create an `ObservableCollection` for each type and bind it to my XAML which takes the properties of each entity and displays them. (For example, creates a textbox with the color and text of a `TextEntity`)

Managing these entities together feels like a bit of a hack. If I have a bunch of collections for each entity, I could just create an `ObservableCollection<MapEntity>`, and add all of the entities to it. This would make handling them easier, such as checking their bounds when a user drags an entity, or updating them via their update method defined in `MapEntity`. Standard inheritance stuff.

The problem comes when using this technique, is there a way to create an `ItemsControl` that is binded to this single collection (Rather than having each `ItemsControl` binded to a collection of `TextEntity`, `LineEntity`, etc), yet only displays elements of a certain type?

For example:

*ViewModel:*

```
public ObvervableCollection<MapEntity> Entities { get; set; //OnPropertyChanged stuff}
...
Entities.Add(new LineEntity(...));
Entities.Add(new TextEntity(...));
```

So, I am adding different `MapEntities` to a single collection rather than multiple ones for each type.

*View:*

Using separate collections, I could bind each `ItemsControl` of items to a specific collection, but using one `Entities` collection, I can not find a way to "filter" elements of a certain type derived from `MapEntity`.

So instead of doing:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding LineEntities}"> <!-- More Stuff -->  </ItemsControl>
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TextEntities}"> <!-- More Stuff -->  </ItemsControl>
```

I want to do:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Entities WHERE type = LineEntity}"> <!-- More Stuff -->  </ItemsControl>
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Entities WHERE type = TextEntity}"> <!-- More Stuff -->  </ItemsControl>
```

(Obviously not valid), but basically I want to "filter" out from the collection only the type that are needed, making it easier to manage in the ViewModel by not having separate collections. (And having to run operations separately on each one because of this)

I'm fairly sure this is not possible, but figured I would ask in case anyone has any ideas, either through XAML or the ViewModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may already know `ItemsControl` automatically selects the correct `ItemTemplate` according to the type of each item.

Define an empty DataTemplate for each type derived from MapEntity like below, so that any `ItemsControl` (without its ItemTemplate explicitly set), choose from these resources.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TextEntity}">
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LineEntity}">
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Now you need to override one of those for each ItemsControl.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Entities}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TextEntity}">
            <!-- Template for text entity -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect! Do you know if it is creating a "blank" element for the ItemControls if type type if not the `DataType`, or will WPF see that only one `DataTemplate` was defined and not bother "trying" to add it to the control?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure about that, but I think ItemsControl shows a dummy text (full namespace and class name of the data type) when no suitable template is found.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at the [CollectionViewSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource(v=vs.110).aspx) class, and use it's filtering capabilities to filter on type.

The nice thing is that it propagates collection changed events from your underlying ObservableCollection.